# Host-only network for Docker container

Tags: network-programming, docker

When running a Docker container, I'd like to set up the container's network so that the container is only able to communicate with the host on the (TCP) ports that the host is listening to. I don't want the container to have access to the internet, or other containers running on the same host, or to the network that the host is connected to. If I was running a VM with something like VMWare, I would choose the "host-only" networking option which creates a private network between the guuest VM and the host with the properties described above.

I've looked into using Docker's `--net=none` but I don't know what direction to go with to configure the network to achieve my goals. TAP/TUN seems to be the way to go, but I'd appreciate some direction

Answer (score 7):

You could create `--internal` network and run a container inside it.

**Creating a network:**

```
docker network create -d bridge --internal hostonly
```

**Running a container:**

```
docker run --network hostonly ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Potential partial answer:

If you can use a unix socket to communicate with your application instead of TCP, then you could use

```
docker run -net=none -v /host-path/socket.sock:/container-path/socket.sock
```

to provide direct communication between the container and the host socket, without allowing any networking out of the container.

Comment: could you do the same but container to container